# equivalent of "double[:,::1] u_tp1 not None" in python?

Tags: python, cython

I am trying to write the short-code below in python (it is from a .pyx file). my issue is the lines with "double[:,::1]" in them. Is there any equivalent in python for it? also, how does "cdef unsigned int i, j" translate to python? I am new to programming and most of what I found online is over my head. any suggestion or help is appreciated.

```
def _step_scalar(
double[:,::1] u_tp1 not None,
double[:,::1] u_t not None,
double[:,::1] u_tm1 not None,
unsigned int x1, unsigned int x2, unsigned int z1, unsigned int z2,
double dt, double ds,
double[:,::1] vel not None):
"""
Perform a single time step in the Finite Difference solution for scalar
waves 4th order in space
"""
cdef unsigned int i, j
for i in xrange(z1, z2):
    for j in xrange(x1, x2):
        u_tp1[i,j] = (2.*u_t[i,j] - u_tm1[i,j]
            + ((vel[i,j]*dt/ds)**2)*(
                (-u_t[i,j + 2] + 16.*u_t[i,j + 1] - 30.*u_t[i,j] +
                 16.*u_t[i,j - 1] - u_t[i,j - 2])/12. +
                (-u_t[i + 2,j] + 16.*u_t[i + 1,j] - 30.*u_t[i,j] +
                 16.*u_t[i - 1,j] - u_t[i - 2,j])/12.))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're type declarations to help Cython speed up the code. Python is dynamically typed (accepts variables of any type) so they aren't meaningful in Cython. Therefore you can get rid of them.

`double[:,::1]` defines the variable as a 2D, C contiguous memoryview of `doubles`. This means the function expects something similar to a 2D numpy array (as this is still what you should pass your Cython function).

`u_tp1` is the variable name. You should keep this.

`not None` tells Cython to assume that you won't pass `None` into the function (so it disables some checks for extra speed). This can be deleted in Python.

`cdef unsigned int i, j` defines `i` and `j` as C integers, for extra speed. In Python `i` and `j` are created when they are needed in the `for` loop so the definition can be deleted completely.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using "cimport cython" command to use the .pyx file. I am going to use your comments to see if I can fix the code for python directly.